# What are the EU criteria for defining a product as 'sustainable'?

Tags: european-union, regulations, environmental

I'm writing an academic paper in the field of material science and was trying to find working guidelines to define product sustainability.

In particular, I was trying to see if, within the EU, there are laws defining the specific standards a product must meet to be considered 'sustainable' (I've read the European Commission has presented policies to regulate sustainable consumption and production), but I don't know how to navigate EU law nor which organ is responsible for enforcing these regulations, so I haven't been able to find a list of criteria for product sustainability.

Does anyone know what these criteria are or how I can find them?

Comment: **is** the word regulated? I know Öko (ecological) is regulated in Germany, but not the equivalent to sustainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect there are no such definitions. It's generally hard to prove a negative, but [the Dutch ACM market watchdog released a report](https://europeanlawblog.eu/2020/10/09/competition-law-and-sustainability-dutch-authority-makes-headway-with-draft-guidelines/) where it specifically addressed this question in the context of missing EU regulations.